# Bold syntax around single character in Redmine

Tags: character, text-editor, redmine, text-formatting

In Redmine's text editor, to make any word bold you have to surround it with an asterisk *  like `*this*`.  My question is how could I make only one character bold?  *t*his does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Textile as the text formatter in Redmine the only way to achieve this seems to be isolating the character with white spaces like this: `bla *a* bla`. I couldn't find another way in Textile.

If you use Markdown as your formatter in Redmine than it's possible to make a single character bold anywhere in the text like this: `bla**b**la`.

You can select the "Text Formatting" in "Administration" - "Settings" on the "General" tab. But be careful because changing the formatting after a while needs a migration job which is stated under the "Text Formatting" box:
"For migrating saved texts from textile to HTML use application from command line: "bundle exec rake easyproject:textile:migrate_all RAILS_ENV=production"

PS: This warning seems to be specific to our Redmine plugin called "Easyredmine". It could be different  or completely nonexistent on a raw Redmine installation.

Comment: I have raw Redmine and under "Text Formatting" only available options are "Textile" or "None".

Comment: Installed the https://github.com/alminium/redmine_redcarpet_formatter plugin and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `*t*<notextile></notextile>his` to achieve this.

Comment: Works for me thanks, although it is a bit inconvenient - but that is not grinderX19 fault.

But it seems his answer was downvoted? Why? Is there a better solution (when using textile)?

Comment: [As per Redmine's Administrator](http://www.redmine.org/issues/1939#note-4) "Wiki Formatting within a Word is not (and won't be) supported. Texile doesn't support this.", 

so grinderX19's workaround  should be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `==*t*==his` to achieve **t**his (more compact then `*t*<notextile></notextile>his`).

But I can't do **d**ata**b**ase with something like this :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach when I needed to bold only one single character:

```
*X&nbsp;*
```

It is combination of actual symbol X and non-breaking space

```
&nbsp;
```

Works well with redmine textile!